# Loading data via a module and a text file in another directory

Tags: python

I have directory structure:

```
main/
__init__.py
     foo/
         __init__.py
         names.py
         names.pickle
     bar/
         __init__.py
         my_module.py
```

names.py has code that works with names.pickle, including loading the pickled data.

However, in my_module.py if I do:

```
from main.foo import names
```

Then I run my_module.py from main/bar, Python complains to me that it can't find names.pickle, presumably because it looks inside main/bar/, not main/foo/.

What is the recommended way to resolve this? Is it to temporarily change os.curdir?

Comment: localy, did you run names.py to see if it loading data from names.pickle or not ?

Comment: @abda2005 yes and it works fine

Comment: certainly , it's the path the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the file location of `names.py` to locate `names.pickle`

```
from main.foo import names
import os

names_pickle = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(names.__file__), 'names.pickle')
```

Each module has a `__file__` attribute that tells where it is located on the file system.

Comment: Is it considered bad practice to perform these actions within main.foo.names? Is it even possible?

Comment: This is just introspection... it's not an action, you are just getting information.  It's definitely possible, I use it in some of my code.  It isn't considered bad practice... you need to locate the `names.pickle` file in a relative way somehow, so you need the `__file__` attribute (or `inspect` module as Phillip pointed out).  Otherwise there is no way to locate data within a package.

Comment: is it possible to do os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'names.pickle') without the names.__file__  like in django ?

Comment: Just `__file__` will give the path to the current file that is calling the command.  As long as that is part of your module and you can find `names.pickle` relative to it, then you can do that too.  What is your objection to `names.__file__`?  How is just `__file__` less objectionable than `name.__file__`?

Comment: I would consider any solution using `__file__` or `module.__file__` way less bad practice than temporarily changing the current directory (as you originally suggested).  Using `__file__` just returns a string.  Changing the directory changes the state of your system.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `inspect` module:

```
import inspect
from main.foo import names

names_pickle = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(inspect.getfile(names)), 'names.pickle')
```